# Bava Kamma 24a: Why is Rabbi Yosei's Analysis sound?

Tags: bava-kamma

## Background

The Mishna in [Bava Kamma 23b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.23b.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states:

> איזהו תם ואיזו מועד מועד כל שהעידו בו שלשה ימים ותם משיחזור בו שלשה ימים דברי ר' יהודה רבי מאיר אומר מועד שהעידו בו שלשה פעמים ותם כל שיהו התינוקות ממשמשין בו ואינו נוגח:
>
> *What is a 'Tam' [ox] and what is a 'Muad'[ox]?*
>
> *A 'Muad' [ox] is one which was warned for **three days** [regarding its goring] and a 'Tam' [ox] is one which reverts [from goring] for three days- These are the words of Rabbi Yehuda.*
>
> ***Rabbi Meir says- a 'Muad' [ox] is one which they warned three times [regarding its goring] and a 'Tam' [ox] is any which children pet and it does not gore***

## Relevant text

The Gemara on [24a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.24a.8?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) brings down a Braisa and states:

> תנו רבנן איזהו מועד כל שהעידו בו שלשה ימים ותם שיהו התינוקות ממשמשין בו ואינו נוגח דברי ר' יוסי ר' שמעון אומר מועד כל שהעידו בו שלש פעמים ולא אמרו שלשה ימים אלא לחזרה בלבד
>
> אמר רב נחמן אמר רב אדא בר אהבה הלכה כר' יהודה במועד שהרי ר' יוסי מודה לו והלכה כרבי מאיר בתם שהרי ר' יוסי מודה לו
>
> אמר ליה רבא לרב נחמן ולימא מר הלכה כרבי מאיר במועד שהרי רבי שמעון מודה לו והלכה כרבי יהודה בתם שהרי רבי שמעון מודה לו
>
> אמר ליה אנא כרבי יוסי סבירא לי דרבי יוסי נימוקו עמו
>
> *The sages taught: **What us a 'Muad'? Any [ox] which they warned for three days [regarding its goring] and a 'Tam' is one which children can pet and it does not gore- these are the words of Rabbi Yosei. Rabbi Shimon says- a Muad is any [ox] which they warned [regarding its goring] three times, and they only stated 'three days' for reverting its behaviour***
>
> Rabbi Nachman says in the name of Rav Ada bar Ahava- The Halacha is like Rabbi Yehuda for a 'Muad' for Rabbi Yosei agrees with it and  the Halacha is like Rabbi Meir for a 'Tam' for Rabbi Yosei agrees with it.
>
> Rava said to Rav Nachman- "let the master say that the Halacha is like Rabbi Meir for a 'Muad' for  Rabbi Shimon agrees with it and the Halacha is like Rabbi Yehuda for a 'Tam' for Rabbi Shimon agrees with it?"
>
> He [Rav Nachman] responded: "I hold like Rabbi Yosei for his analysis is with him?" [i.e. sound]

## My Question

The Gemara proceeds without mentioning *why* Rabbi Yosei's analysis is sound. Why is Rav Nachman's response sufficient for Rava's question?

Answer (score 1):

The [Steinsaltz's commentary](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.24a.8?lang=bi&p2=Steinsaltz_on_Bava_Kamma.24a.8&lang2=bi) on that gemara is as follows:
(bolded words are the gemara, unbolded is the Steinsaltz's explanation)

> **אנא** [אני] **כר' יוסי סבירא לי** [סבור אני] ואני פוסק לגמרי כפי שיטתו, **שר' יוסי נימוקו** (טעמו וסברתו) **עמו** ולכן ראוי לפסוק כשיטתו בכל מקום.
>
> **I** [R' Nachman] **hold like R' Yosi** and I always follow his halachic decisions, **since "*nimmuko imo*"**- ie he has sound reasoning and rationale, and therefore I find it fit to follow his halachic decisions everywhere

Evidently, R' Nachman says that R' Yosi is such a big Talmid Chacham that he (R' Nachman) felt it was enough to just follow his halachic rulings, no further explanation needed.

Rava not responding could either mean he accepts this explanation, or by not responding could mean he doesn't accept it, not sure.

Comment: But contrast with Eruvin 13b about why we don't follow R. Meir.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Rava accepted. Rava himself says RY nimuko ymo in Eruvin 14b

> אמר רבא האלהים אמרה וגמירנא לה מיניה ומאי טעמא קא הדר ביה משום דר' יוסי נימוקו

So, he accredited this argument in BK

This argument was already used by Rabbi. Gittin 67a

> גופא אמר שמואל אמר רבי הלכה כרבי יוסי דאמר מילי לא מימסרן לשליח אמר לפניו ר"ש ברבי מאחר שר"מ וחנינא איש אונו חולקין על רבי יוסי מה ראה רבי לומר הלכה כר' יוסי אמר לו שתוק בני שתוק לא ראית את ר' יוסי אילמלי ראיתו נמוקו עמו דתניא איסי בן יהודה היה מונה שבחן של חכמים ר"מ חכם וסופר ר' יהודה חכם לכשירצה ר' טרפון גל של אגוזין ר' ישמעאל חנות מיוזנת ר"ע אוצר בלום ר' יוחנן בן נורי קופת הרוכלים רבי אלעזר בן עזריה קופה של בשמים משנת ר' אליעזר בן יעקב קב ונקי ר' יוסי נמוקו עמו רבי שמעון טוחן הרבה ומוציא קימעא תנא משכח קימעא ומה שמוציא אינו מוציא אלא סובין וכן אמר ר"ש לתלמידיו בניי שנו מדותי 
>   שמדותי תרומות מתרומות מידותיו של ר"ע
>
> Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi said to his son: Be silent, my son; be silent. You did not see Rabbi Yosei, as, if you had seen him, you would know that his reasoning [nimmuko] accompanies his statements. Therefore, I deem his opinion most reliable.
>   Toggle Reader Menu Display Settings
>   טוען מידע...
>   67a
>   אמרו לסופר ויכתוב ולפלוני ופלוני ויחתמו ומשום כיסופא דסופר חיישי ומחתמי חד מהנך סהדי וסופר בהדייהו ובעל לא אמר הכי

Tell a scribe and he will write the document and tell so-and-so and so-and-so and they will sign it. And due to the shame of the scribe, who asks: Don’t you consider me a sufficiently upright person to sign the document as a witness, the agents are concerned to avoid that disgrace and have one of those witnesses and the scribe sign together with him, and the husband did not say to do so. The bill of divorce is invalid because it was signed contrary to the husband’s instructions, and the agents will mistakenly think it is valid.

כיון דאמר מר כשר ולא תעשה כן בישראל לא שכיח

The Gemara answers: Since the Master said, as cited later, that such a bill of divorce is valid, however, it shall not be done in Israel, as the husband himself should appoint the scribe and the witnesses, it is an uncommon case for the husband to appoint an agent to arrange the bill of divorce, and the Sages do not issue a decree for cases that are uncommon.

וליחוש דילמא אמר להו לבי תרי אמרו לסופר ויכתוב ואתם חתומו ואזלי הנך משום כיסופא דסופר ומחתמי ליה לסופר בהדי חד מינייהו ובעל לא אמר הכי אמרי הא נמי כשר ולא תעשה הוא

The Gemara asks: And let us be concerned lest the husband say to two people: Tell the scribe and he will write the document and you sign it, and these two, due to the shame of the scribe, go and have the scribe sign the document together with one of them, and the husband did not say to do so. The Sages say: In this case too, it is valid; however, it shall not be done. This too is uncommon, and there is neither concern nor a decree.

הניחא למ"ד כשר ולא תעשה אלא למ"ד כשר ותעשה מאי איכא למימר

The Gemara responds: This works out well according to the one who said in this case as well: It is valid; however, it shall not be done. But according to the one who said: It is valid and it may be done, i.e., it is permitted ab initio, what is there to say?

אלא רבי יוסי תרתי אמר ושמואל סבר לה כוותיה בחדא ופליג עליה בחדא

Rather, this is the explanation. Rabbi Yosei stated two halakhot: The first is that verbal directives cannot be delegated to an agent. The second is that even when the husband said: Tell another to write the document, this agency cannot be transferred to another person. And Shmuel holds in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yosei in one case, i.e., that verbal directives cannot be delegated to an agent, and he disagrees with him in one case, as Shmuel holds that if the husband explicitly said: Tell another to write the document, this agency can be transferred.

גופא אמר שמואל אמר רבי הלכה כרבי יוסי דאמר מילי לא מימסרן לשליח אמר לפניו ר"ש ברבי מאחר שר"מ וחנינא איש אונו חולקין על רבי יוסי מה ראה רבי לומר הלכה כר' יוסי

§ With regard to the previously cited matter itself, Shmuel says that Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi says: The halakha is in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yosei, who says: Verbal directives cannot be delegated to an agent. Rabbi Shimon, son of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi, said before his father: Since Rabbi Meir and Rabbi Ḥanina of Ono, who hold that verbal directives can be delegated to an agent, disagree with Rabbi Yosei, what led Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi to say that the halakha is in accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Yosei?

אמר לו שתוק בני שתוק לא ראית את ר' יוסי אילמלי ראיתו נמוקו עמו

Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi said to his son: Be silent, my son; be silent. You did not see Rabbi Yosei, as, if you had seen him, you would know that his reasoning [nimmuko] accompanies his statements. Therefore, I deem his opinion most reliable.

דתניא איסי בן יהודה היה מונה שבחן של חכמים ר"מ חכם וסופר ר' יהודה חכם לכשירצה ר' טרפון גל של אגוזין ר' ישמעאל חנות מיוזנת ר"ע אוצר בלום ר' יוחנן בן נורי קופת הרוכלים רבי אלעזר בן עזריה קופה של בשמים משנת ר' אליעזר בן יעקב קב ונקי ר' יוסי נמוקו עמו רבי שמעון טוחן הרבה ומוציא קימעא

This is as it is taught in a baraita that Isi ben Yehuda would recount the praise of the Sages by characterizing each of them: Rabbi Meir, a scholar and scribe; Rabbi Yehuda, a scholar when he chooses to be one; Rabbi Tarfon, a pile of nuts, as, just as when one removes a nut from a pile all the other nuts fall, so too, when a student would ask Rabbi Tarfon with regard to one matter, he would cite sources from all the disciplines of the Torah; Rabbi Yishmael, a well-stocked store; Rabbi Akiva, a full storehouse; Rabbi Yoḥanan ben Nuri, a peddler’s basket, in which there is a small amount of each product; Rabbi Elazar ben Azarya, a basket of fragrant spices, as everything he says is reasonable; the mishna of Rabbi Eliezer ben Ya’akov is measured [kav] and immaculate; Rabbi Yosei, his reasoning accompanies his statements; Rabbi Shimon grinds much and removes little.